# Floating elements horizontally from top to bottom and left to right

Tags: css, position, css-float, horizontal-scrolling

I want to create a div which has horizontall scrollbar. The elements inside it should display from top to bottom and left to right.

```
1 3 6
2 4 7
  5 8
```

The height of each element is variable (and might not be the same in each element) so depending on the screensize elements position might change, for example:

```
1 3 5 7
2 4 6
```

or in extreme:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If I float:left the inside elements, the display is like follows:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nx88G/

Is there a way to achieve this using only CSS?

I know I can achieve this with a javscript plugin such as [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/layout-modes.html#masonryHorizontal) (click masonryHorizontal)

Comment: From my answer : using `column-count` in your fiddle, since you set an `height` to .container  and  i gave no `columns` numbers,  it  keeps drawing as many columns needed : http://jsfiddle.net/nx88G/5/ if `container` has no `height` defined , columns will grow vertically and fill as much as possible width avalaible.

Comment: Thanks this is great. Two questions just in case you know. Is there a way to use max-column-width similarly to max-width? Can you point me any direction for at least IE9 compatibility? Thanks

Comment: you can set % for column-width and set a max-width to the main container itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only close to the question, i can think of a mix of `column` CSS and eventually `writing-mode`.

test: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mGJfK/

markup used many times in body : `<b> inline-box </b>`

columns :

```
body {
  column-width:9em;
}
b {
  display:inline-block;
  width:8em;
}
```

and experimental writing-mode added :

```
body {
  writing-mode:rl-tb;/* IEs */
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-bt;
  -moz-writing-mode: horizontal-bt;/* FF fails here */
  -o-writing-mode: horizontal-bt;
  writing-mode: horizontal-bt;
}
```

Comment: Im checking the codepen with chrome and it displays elements from bottom-top, instead of top-bottom.

Comment: @Alvaro this is the `writing-mode` in action, you can drop it :)

Comment: Fascinating property I didnt know about,it even acts responsive http://jsfiddle.net/WnLB4/

Comment: @Alvaro only under webkit at this time I believe

Comment: I added moz prefix. It looks ok in IE11,Opera, Firefox and Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/WnLB4/1/

Comment: oh yes , it does , i did not noticed so far it work responsive  too in those browser

Comment: changing `horizontal-bt` to `horizontal-tb` makes it top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

try using the `display:flex` property on your container

```
#container {
    height:100%;
    width:500px;
    background:black;

  /* added CSS */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```